# Configure keep alive timeout on Jetty 6.1.19

Tags: configuration, jetty, keep-alive

How do you set the timeout on keep alive connections to the Jetty web server (in my case v6.1.19)?

I would like to configure how long Jetty keeps connections open when a client requests keep alive. Currently it seems indefinite.

Answer (score 2):

This can be configured by setting the "maxIdleTime" on the socket connector. See [Configuring Connectors](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Configuring+Connectors)

For example in jetty.xml

```
<Call name="addConnector">
    <Arg>
    <New class="org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
        <Set name="maxIdleTime">10000</Set>
```

From the manual:

> Set the maximum Idle time for a connection, which roughly translates to the Socket.setSoTimeout(int) call, although with NIO implementations other mechanisms may be used to implement the timeout.